# How to avoid DotNetNuke with another ASP.NET application conflicts

Tags: asp.net, iis7

Web have the following scenario:

- A generic web developed using
  DotNetNuke
- A b2b web application developed using
  ASP.NET + Silverlight

What we want to do is the following:

- When a client goes to
  www.myCompanyDomain.com the web that
  the client access is the Dotnetnuke
  Web.
- When a client goes to
  www.myCompanyDomain.com/b2b the web
  loaded is the B2B web.

The problem is that when we install the DotNetNuke application into the main directory of our web server the Web.Config configuration file is inherited by any application installed in a subdirectory, causing the B2B application to fail.

In order to have a working installation we have to install the DotNetNuke web in a subdirectory and the B2B web in another, but this make impossible to access the DotNetNuke web directly from www.MyCompanyDomain.com

How can we install the applications and configure the IIS to have the wanted behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to verify is that the 'B2B' application was defined in IIS as an application (not just a virtual directory).  It sounds like the issue you are having is with web.config inheritance.  Have a look at the following article which may provide some helpful tips on what you can do with the B2B application to break inheritance:

http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/how-to-disable-web-config-inheritance-for-child-applications-in-subfolders-in-asp-net.aspx

Info on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx

An easy approach might of course be to install each of DotNetNuke and your B2B app in sub folders, then put a 301 redirect on the root of your www.myCompanyDomain.com.  Not the most ideal, but would certainly be quick to put in place.  I would recommend looking at correcting the web.config inheritance.

Comment: B2B application is actually configured as an application with the corresponding AppPool and other configurations.

Comment: If we install each application in a separate sub folder, can we define the sub folder containing DotNetNuke to be the default destination of all requests to http://www.MyCompanyDomain.com?

Comment: The physical folder on the file system does not really matter since you can point the document root of a website or virtual directory to any file system location.  The issue you are having is that the web.config of the B2B application is inheriting the settings of the root website (in this case DNN).  You either need to break the inheritance or install the two applications in different "branches" of the website.  If you want DNN to be the default site and it is installed to a different folder, you will need to 301 redirect MyCompanyDomain.com to something like MyCompanyDomain.com/DNN.

Comment: In the MSDN article:  "Configuration settings for virtual directories are independent of physical directory structure, and virtual directories must be organized carefully to avoid configuration problems."  Hope that helps too.